# How to block/ disallow certain filetypes in codeigniter?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I've been trying to figure it out for a while now and can't seem to find any solution posted anywhere before. I want to allow almost all file types excluding some in codeigniter controller method. Here's **my code:**

```
function checkFileType($ext){
        if(in_array($ext, array('ade','adp','bat','chm','cmd','com','cpl','dll','dmg','exe','hta','ins','isp','jar','js','jse','lib','lnk','mde','msc','msi','msp','mst','nsh','pif','scr','sct','shb','sys','vb','vbe','vbs','vxd','wsc','wsf','wsh')))
            return '';
        else
            return $ext;
    }

/* Upload files */
public function store_files(){
    $data='';
    $userdir = 'uploads/files/'.$this->getCategory().$this->getID();
    $this->load->library('upload');
    if (!file_exists($userdir)) {
        mkdir($userdir, 0777, true);
    }
    $file = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    $ext = substr(strrchr($file, '.'), 1);
    $config = array(
        'upload_path'=>$userdir,
        'allowed_types'=>checkFileType($ext),
        'max_width'=>0,
        'max_height'=>0,
        'max_size'=>0,
        'encrypt_name'=>TRUE,
        'file_ext_tolower'=>TRUE,
    );
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
        print_r($this->upload->display_errors());
    } else {
        foreach($this->upload->data() as $key=>$value){
            if($value)
                $data.= '<b>'.$key.'</b> : '.$value.'<br><br>';
        }
        echo $data;
    }
 }
```

**Note:**

- On echoing `$ext` in the `store_files()` function, it shows the correct extension as string.
- I'm trying to allow all extension types except those that match in the `checkFileType()` method.
- If I manually specify the file extensions in the order `(gif|png|pdf|pptx...)` it works fine, but I can't seem to make use of '*' either because it allows all file extensions including the ones I want to block.

Comment: https://garrettstjohn.com/articles/codeigniter-file-upload-setting-disallowed-file-types/

Comment: @SaadSuri I extended my library in the application directory with the filename as MY_upload.php and class as MY_upload but when trying to upload now, it shows "Message: Declaration of MY_UPLOAD::initialize() should be compatible with CI_Upload::initialize(array $config = Array, $reset = true)"

Comment: Means it has to have the same declaration e.g. `initialize($config = array(), $reset = true)`

Comment: Although it seems that the initialize function has changed since the article has been written. I think you can get away with not even including the initialize function in MY_Upload and instead include only a `public $disallowed_types` and the top of the MY_Upload file and it should be picked up by the init. That being said, using your method, you could always return some random string like `time()` instead of `return '';` and it should work as expected (bit of a hack though).

Comment: @Alex Yeah, I figured it out a while back but thank you for the response as well :)

Comment: Did you get it working? Which method did you use?